# When Is It Time To Get the Department Involved With MSc Progress?

Tags: phd, thesis, masters

I am a masters student approaching my expected graduation date (September), the problem however is that I have not a single result to speak to. However, this is not due to of a lack of serious effort and time invested on my part. The problem that I thought of was slated to be worth publishing in a top journal and the idea and execution that I had was considered good enough to be accepted as an abstract to two top conferences.

My issue is that my problem is simply too hard to solve (computationally speaking). At the beginning of the research, I simply would not have known or understood this and so I kept working on it and working on it and as of last month the stark reality hit me that my original idea had to be abandoned. I even found a possible path forward to solve my problem which is used extensively in the field of engineering and operations research, but I was told not to use it by my advisor.

I tried to simplify the idea which then requires me to completely change the method that I use to analyze the problem (changing the method sporadically also means my research question has to be altered). However, in order for me to use this new method I have to learn how to program with a new set of libraries, and solving my problem is non-trivial because I have nobody I can speak to locally about implementing the problem in the programming language I use (Python). Long story short, I am unable to implement this new method because I cannot figure it out and have nobody I can talk to locally about it. What feels even weirder is that I am trying to use a method for the sake of salvaging a problem, and this feels very unnatural to me as an inexperienced researcher.

I am three months away and I have no results. My masters program appears like it is going to take 2.5-3 years to complete, and on top of that, I will ultimately need to present something to my committee that I am not really proud of. Looking forward, I am somewhat worried that PhD programs might not be interested if they see a masters student that took a much longer time to complete a masters program with no publications to speak of. Furthermore, I am concerned that funding for my project could run out from my supervisor, and then I would either need to get a job to continue on or try and find a new project with a different professor in the department.

No matter the case, I am sure that I will graduate at some point, but I am very concerned about how the end result will reflect on me if I wanted to apply to PhD programs afterwards.

Are these common occurrences in the paths of masters students or is it time I get somebody outside of my supervisor involved? It’s a difficult decision because I feel that I lack the experience and judgement to make such an important call. Furthermore, how could I make the best of this situation when I am applying for PhD programs in the future? I

Comment: What field is this? Pure math or something applied? What country?

Comment: The country is Canada and the field is resource economics - the ‘complexity problem’ and the modelling approach is based in Operations Research / Math Programming / Optimization.

Comment: Guess I can't help much other than to suggest that you work it out with your advisor. It may be that enough progress has been made to get enough insight into a difficult problem that the thesis and the degree are not in danger. Many problems are beyond scheduling.